# Red icons in Xcode debugger

Tags: xcode, xcode-debugger

I have been looking all over for an explanation on this and I can't find anything in Apple's docs or anywhere else.

In the debugging view in Xcode I see two red icons, one is a person (just like the blue ones) and the other is what looks like a car sounding it's horn next to the main app name.

I was wondering if anyone knew what they are, or what they mean, if I should be concerned about them, or can otherwise point me in a direction to learn more.

[image]

Comment: The "car sounding it's horn" icon is probably your application icon.

Comment: @MartinR It's not my app icon

Comment: Myabe the icon represents a `crash` — as in a car crashing. The other red one is indicating where.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for the tip. Do you by any chance know how to read that or how I would find where that's coming from?

Comment: @l'L'l Could a crash be the case even if the app still runs as expected?

Comment: @Garrett: Which version of Xcode are you running, and where exactly are you seeing that info (In Xcode my debugger doesn't look quite like that). I've never seen the car icon, so it was just a guess as to what it might be.

Comment: @l'L'l I gotcha. I am running Xcode 9.2, I am seeing the icon in the debugger section with a drop down menu that shows all the threads.